# Users and group membership

Tags: privileges, users

My server is installed by my provider with a default user (root and another user, lets say here **johndoe**).
I lack some experience to know if everything is well set.
Let's say I add the group admin. Then I need to add johndoe to this group.
I end up with the following when I read /etc/group :

```
...
**johndoe**:x:1000:
...
admin:x:1001:**johndoe**
```

This numbers, with the letters… I just don't have a clue.
The admin's group is set with the following :

```
%admin ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

I need to give johndoe the most privileges possible; do I have anything else to do?
Hope my question is not too random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding that `%admin ALL=(ALL)       ALL` is in `/etc/sudoers` file, there are three ways of gaining root privileges:

1. In order to execute a command with root privileges you should run `sudo command`.
2. To open a shell with root privileges but environment variables from **johndoe** you can invoke `sudo -s`.
3. Also, if you really want to run a root console (with environment variables of root user) you can execute `sudo su -` and you will have a root shell.